Picture book read in the 1990s. A young girl encounters a wizard who gifts her the moon
I'm looking to identify this picture book I read in the 1990s. I remember the illustrations being gorgeous, opaque, and watercolour but pastel soft tones. Very intricate/delicate.
There was a wizard, and the girl was at home in a flowing white nightdress. The moon was a distinct part of the story. A wizard came to her room, and I think she needed to clean her room.
One illustration was her floating in a swirling room and magic all around her. I've been searching for this for several years.

I wonder if this could be Once In A Blue Moon, a picturebook by Julie Leibrich and illustrated by Jacquelyn E. Lane. It was published in 1995, and so is consistent with being read in the 1990s.
The story deals with a girl named Amy, who dances so well that the Blue Wizard visits her to give her a present. From the blurb on google books:

Amy loves to dance, and one day her dancing attracts an unusual and
special visitor who offers her the chance for a wish to come true. But
Amy's wish is beyond the power of the Wizard of Tantalus-I, until the
music meets the moon and anything is possible.

(the wish is for her to dance with the moon).
The illustrations are indeed very intricate and delicate. On her webpage, the artist, Lane, recalls that:

The brief for Once In A Blue Moon...required that only every second
page could be colour. So as not to jar the senses between the
greyscale and the colour pages, I incorporated graphite pencil into
every colour page.

In case it jogs your memory, here is the cover and one of the interior pages.


Clara I can't thank you enough. You've no idea how much this means to me. I am eternally grateful! Words cannot express
